# un array de 2 objetos en una req al chequear que ambos estén en db mediante promise me devuelve un array de arrays mongodb javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongoose

soy bastante nuevo en mongodb, estoy con un problema en el carro de compras. Cuando intento generar la "transacción" y en mi carro tengo un array con 2 objetos (dos productos diferentes) que me llegan de la `req`. Lo que intento es evaluar que la `req` no este adulterada, y coincida con los datos en `mongodb`.

Mi problema es que en el código que escribí solo me chequea el primer producto del array y el segundo no, al crear la compra me termina pasando los dos productos sin chequear el segundo en la base de datos. No puedo encontrar la solución para que corrobore los dos productos, ya que si yo le cambio el `id` al segundo, este pasa igual como aprobado, pero en cambio si solo cambio el `id` al primer producto sale rechazada.

Espero que me puedan ayudar y se entienda lo que quiero explicar, gracias

**esta es la req que me llega**

```js
products =[
  { id: '6080508bed7da0127011e696', price: 140, quantity: 2 },
  { id: '60d2b8bff5922907282dcc94', price: 170, quantity: 3 }
]
```

este es el código que se me ocurrió y me devuelve un array con cada objeto en un array diferente

```js
const approvePurchaseProducts = async (products) => {
    try {
        
        const checkProducts = products.map((product) =>
            Product.find({
                _id: product.id,
                price: product.price,
                avaible_quantity: { $gte: product.quantity },
                enable: true,
            })
        );
        

        const approvePurchaseResult = await Promise.all(checkProducts);
        if (approvePurchaseResult.length === products.length) {
            console.log(approvePurchaseResult);
            return true;
        }
        //return false;*/
        throw new Error('los datos de productos no son validos');
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
};
```

**esto es lo que me devuelve el `console.log(approvedPurchaseResult)`**

```js
[
  [
    {
      condition: 'new',
      photos: [],
      enable: true,
      sold: 6,
      _id: 6080508bed7da0127011e696,
      title: 'detergente',
      price: 140,
      description: 'mejor de todes',
      avaible_quantity: 14,
      ts_create: 2021-04-22T03:00:00.000Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-06-24T01:52:37.883Z
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      condition: 'new',
      photos: [Array],
      enable: true,
      sold: 6,
      _id: 60d2b8bff5922907282dcc94,
      title: 'sopapas',
      price: 170,
      description: 'gran sopapa',
      avaible_quantity: 14,
      createdAt: 2021-06-23T04:29:51.076Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-06-24T01:52:37.884Z,
      __v: 0
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Hola, primero antes que nada, nunca pongas el precio en el front end como dato de valor el precio de un producto en el front end es meramente ilustrativo, lo justo y necesario para mandar en la request es la id del producto y la cantidad por producto. Luego en la base de adtos realiza la operacion por el precio en lista que obtienes haciendo una consulta a la base de datos para obtener toda la data importante en el checkout.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu aclaración. Entiendo, quizá me exprese mal. Esto es el back, lo que hago es consultar la base de datos. Yo arme la APIREST, el problema es que no puedo chequear que los datos que me llegan de la request en un array de obj.

Comment: Chequea mi respuesta, un saludo.

Comment: gracias, no conocia array.flat(). lo voy a implementar. muchas gracias!

Comment: Creo que es mejor que simplemente uses findOne en lugar de find, gasta menos recursos por lo tanto menos tiempo para encontrar en la base de datos, pero bueno espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: Me funciono perfecto aplicando el .findOne y luego aplique un .includes(null) para filtrar. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Extracto de mi comentario anterior**:

Hola, primero antes que nada, nunca pongas el precio en el front end como dato de valor el precio de un producto en el front end es meramente ilustrativo, lo justo y necesario para mandar en la request es la id del producto y la cantidad por producto. Luego en el backend realiza la operación por el precio en lista que obtienes haciendo una consulta a la base de datos (y para obtener toda la data importante en el checkout).

**El problema**:

Básicamente el problema radica en el `map` y lo que retorna `find`, el método `find` de una colección de mongo retorna un array de resultados porque está hecha para encontrar multiples coincidencia, por lo que al mapear y procesar todas las promises cada una de ellas devuelve un array con un objeto dentro que es el único que coincidió con el query. **En síntesis básicamente estas mapeando un array con un objeto dentro de un array**. De aquí derivan todos los problemas de que si pudiste checar uno y el otro no y todo eso...

**Solución**:

**Hay un par de cosas que podrías hacer**.

1. Lo mas fácil es usar el método `findOne` que debería devolver un objeto si encuentra y un `null` si no, en cualquier driver u orm de mongo:

```javascript
const checkProducts = products.map((product) =>
  Product.findOne(...requirements)
);
```

2. Trabajar con el resultado que ya tienes usando un array flat:

```js
const ejemploFlat = [
  [
    { id: 1 }
  ],
  [
    { id: 2 }
  ]
]

console.log(ejemploFlat.flat())
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.